# Java2D vs Javafx Canvas performance

Tags: java, performance, javafx-2

I'm working on a java program which draws complex fractal shapes on screen, and allows the user to "zoom in" and move around to explore those shapes. This means that computation has to be made in order to display the fractal, and that a certain frame rate has to be achieved (about 20 fps or more).

I have a few methods in mind that I could use to achieve this, but I'm wondering which one would have the best performance.

First, I'm thinking that could use a blank `Image` (`BufferedImage`, specifically) and it's `Graphics2D` context to draw the fractal offscreen, and then pass it to the UI which draws it to the screen. This would mean the creation of a lot of Image types, which I guess is memory expensive.

A similar option would be to create two Images, and then alternate between drawing on the second one while showing the first one, and vice-versa. Would this method yield better performances?

My third choice is to go with the Canvas API of javafx, and use `Canvas` instead of `Image` while essentially doing the same thing (offscreen drawing).

What would give me the best results? Or is there something else I should consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a (non-animated) fractal generator in JavaFX. I used a WritableImage and calls to setColor on its PixelWriter. I generated the WritableImage in a Task and returned the Image from the Task's call method; then I simply updated an ImageView's image with the generated image. Another option would be to generate the colors in the Task, as an array of ints or bytes, and copy them in bulk into a single WritableImage by calling one of the setPixels() methods. I think either of these would perform pretty well.

As I understand it, a Canvas in JavaFX caches its drawing commands, and then executes them all when rendered; I don't think this would perform as well. But I may be wrong on that.

Comment: Do you know if it is better to have two WritableImages I pass between a Task and the UI rather than always re-instantiating one?

Comment: I doubt it would make any difference. I think the cost of creating the WritableImage is completely negligible relative to the cost of computing the pixel data. If it did perform better, then I think using a single WritableImage and letting the Task compute an array of ints or bytes would perform equally well and would probably keep the code cleaner. You might need to just experiment...

Comment: Well you are using a Task, so the GUI thread has to synchronize with the thread which has executed the task: it can wait a long time (sufficient to be visible), it can make the animation lag or be non linear (sometimes fast, sometimes slow). I think it is way better to use Canvas as the result will be quite smoother.